# JavaScript, v8, and function printing

Tags: javascript

In node.js (or v8/chrome), can I rely on using string concatenation for getting the code behind a function?

for instance, in node.js

```
var f = function(x) { return x; }
console.log(f);
```

shows "[Function]" while

```
console.log("" + f);
```

shows "function(x) { return x;}"

is this a reliable semantic? Is this in the ECMA spec somewhere?

Comment: one logs a reference to the object, the other logs the object casted as a string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would say yes, since you are using V8.

What the String contatenation is really doing behind the scenes, is to invoke the `Function.prototype.toString` method, for example:

```
var str = "" + f;
```

Is roughly equivalent to:

```
var str = f.toString();
```

This method provides an *implementation-dependent* string representation of the function, it can vary between implementations, for example whitespace, or optimizations can me done.

But since you are targeting an specific implementations I think you won't have any problem.

If you are getting `"[object Function]"` it's because (oddly) the `Object.prototype.toString` is being executed instead the `Function.prototype.toString` one, e.g.:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(function () {}); // "[object Function]"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of V8 what the implementation specific code will do is to return the source of the function as passed into the engine.  V8 doesn't have a byte code so it doesn't disassemble the byte code to reconstruct the function source.  It just keeps the source around in case it is ever asked to do toString() on a function.

Comment: AFAIK the ECMAScript spec says that `Function.toString()` should return the actual code of the function if available.